# C# How to use CoreWebView2PrintSettings correctly?

Tags: c#, webview2, windows-forms-core

I'm using `PrintToPdfAsync` to print the content of my WebView in pdf, but when trying to adjust the top margin I'm not getting a response. The file is created but the margin comes as default.

```
CoreWebView2PrintSettings printSettings = _instance.webView21.CoreWebView2.Environment.CreatePrintSettings();
printSettings.Orientation = CoreWebView2PrintOrientation.Landscape;
printSettings.MarginTop = 100;
_instance.webView21.CoreWebView2.PrintToPdfAsync(output, printSettings)
```

Answer (score 4):

The unit for margins is inches, and the value can't exceed the page height (default is 11 inches). See the [WebView2 Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2printsettings.margintop?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1587.40#microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2printsettings-margintop).